# Laravel using carbon to get current quarter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

How can I use Carbon to determine the current quarter? I.e. I would like to get hold of the date when the quarter started and the date when it ends.

I tried the intuitive `echo new Carbon('this quarter');` way which doesn't work, but I guess they don't have one for quarters.

---

I figured it out, I did:

```
$query->where(DB::raw('QUARTER(FT.created_at)'), Carbon::now()->quarter);
$query->where(DB::raw('YEAR(FT.created_at)'), '=', Carbon::now()->year);
```

But now I am struggling with how to get the start and end date of the last quarter.

Comment: What date would you want it to return?  Or do you just want to get the current quarter number of the created date?

Comment: The date as returned by Carbon::now()->toDateString()

Comment: Do you want just to check whether the date is in last quarter?

Comment: @mininoz Yes that's right, it's for a filter I'm making.

Comment: @imperium2335 You are using `QUARTER(FT.created_at)`, So you might don't need to be worry about the start or end date of the quarter anymore.  Why don't you just pass 4 into the query?

Comment: @mininoz The problem I am having is when it crosses a year. I am in the first quarter, and filter to show the last quarter, that needs to constrain the date by year as well as quarter (4).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `firstOfQuarter` and `lastOfQuarter` methods for determining the beginning and end dates of a quarter...

```
$date = new \Carbon\Carbon('-3 months');
$firstOfQuarter = $date->firstOfQuarter();
$lastOfQuarter = $date->lastOfQuarter();
```

Answer (score 4):

I think I have solved it:

```
...
case 9:
                    $a = Carbon::now();
                    $a->month($a->month-3);
                    $lastQuarter = $a->quarter;
                    $query->where(DB::raw('QUARTER(FT.created_at)'), $lastQuarter);
                    $query->where(DB::raw('YEAR(FT.created_at)'), $a->year);
                    break;
...
```

Please let me know a nicer way to do this if there is one, your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more to the answer above, the actual methods that should be use is the following methods:

```
$date = new \Carbon\Carbon('-3 months'); // for the last quarter requirement
$date->startOfQuarter(); // the actual start of quarter method
$date->endOfQuarter(); // the actual end of quarter method (with time 23:59:59.999999)
```

the following are not exactly correct:

```
$date->firstOfQuarter(); /* use this method when you wish to get the first
                            occurrence of a given day in the current quarter, its 
                            fallback works similar to the startOfQuarter() method */
$date->lastOfQuarter(); /* this is where the problem located, unlike the
                           endOfQuarter() method, this method return the start of a
                           day (with time 00:00:00.000000) (because the method is
                           designed to get the last occurrence of a given day in the
                           current quarter */
```

Answer (score 0):

- To find the current start and end date of the quarter with current date as input and format the date with in custom format.

**

> **$yyyymm = current date(); $date = new \Carbon\Carbon($yyyymm);**
> **$ProfileData['date_from'] = $date->firstOfQuarter()->format('Ymd');**
> **$ProfileData['date_to'] = $date->endOfQuarter()->format('Ymd');**

**

Answer (score 0):

Return the quarter for a given date.

```
$date = Carbon::parse($timestamp);
$date->quarter;
```

Comment: For me: `> $quarter = Carbon\Carbon::parse($myModel->end_date)->quarter;` worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Return the quarter First And Last Date

```
$firstOfQuarter = Carbon::now()->firstOfQuarter()->format('Y-m-d');

$endOfQuarter = Carbon::now()->endOfQuarter()->format('Y-m-d');
```